# How does this snippet work exactly? "pk=request.POST['choice']"

Tags: python, django, django-views

This comes from part 4 of the polls application tutorial from the Django documentation. I am told that it fetches the id of the of the selected choice as a string. I would like to know exactly *how* it does this. Here is some context:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Choice, Question
# ...
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Comment: I do not understand where request.[POST] looks for to find the 'choice'. I get that it looks for submitted data but I don't see where 'choice' is. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet, you should understand that the `question_id` comes from the path you have defined. For more information, look at the [django url dispatcher documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/).

For example, you should post the id of a choice to a url like the below (note that the exact wording will depend on the url path that you have defined):

```
localhost:8000/questions/1/
```

For this url, if you post the id of a choice and there is a choice with the posted id, `request.POST['choice']` will fetch the posted id. The
code snippet will then increment the votes of that choice for the question with 1 as id.

`request.POST` is a dictionary that refers to the submitted data of the http request. As with any other dictionary, you can pass keys to `request.POST` to get the value.

Comment: I think I see now where the choice id is coming from. The html that displays the previous page has this snippet: id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" as an attribute for <input>. By iterating over each choice for the particular question, it assigns each choice a unique id number based on its position in the for loop when it was iterated over. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes you are right. doesnt matter how you post the choice to your url. in can be done by html form or any tool like postman or python library.

Answer (score 0):

Html from previous page:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
<br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
```

This loop will create radio buttons with the same name "choice". Multiple radios sharing the same name is called RADIO GROUP.

When the above form is submitted with a radio button selected, the form's data includes an entry in the form choice=value. (The value is different for each radio button in our case)

Therefore, this snippet `pk=request.POST['choice']` access the value (`value="{{ choice.id }}`)of selected radio from the radio group.

I had the same question and the following link helped me answer it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio